# Perform replacement based on another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes:

```
item   |  label  
 213      'red'
 112      'green'
 332      'orange'
...
```

and another dataframe that essentially behaves like a dictionary:

```
old_label  | new_label
 'red'       'red and bright'
 'orange'    'mild orange'
```

How can I apply the mapping from the second dataframe to the first, to get:

```
item   |  label  
 213      'red and bright'
 112      'green'
 332      'mild orange'
...
```

ignoring the elements which are not found in the second dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) by another `Series`:

```
df1['label'] = df1['label'].replace(df2.set_index('old_label')['new_label'])
```

Or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), but because returned `NaN`s for not matched values repalce by original values with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1['label'] = df1['label'].map(df2.set_index('old_label')['new_label']).fillna(df1['label'])
```